# Communication channel between a windows app and UWP app

Tags: c#, winforms, websocket, uwp

I have a uwp project and a windows app (net5).
Both are installed in the same machine (same will happen in production), but the uwp is installed using sideloading, not on windows store.

The windows app gets some data by listening to a wss port. I have to pass those data from the windows app to the uwp app and also wait for a response back from it.

To do this internal communication I came across the AppServiceBridgeSamples in this repo https://github.com/microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples but it is outdated and I can't use it.

Is there any alternatives to it? What would be the easiest implementation to achieve this?

Any suggestions/comments are appreciated.

Comment: Currently, the general way to implement a communication channel between a UWP app and a windows app is by using App service. This is not outdated. If you don't want to use the App service, you have to build your own socket server so that both of your apps could communicate with it. Another way is that your windows app could save the data in local file and load them in the UWP app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, the general way to implement a communication channel between a UWP app and a windows app is by using App service. This is not outdated. If you don't want to use the App service, you have to build your own socket server so that both of your apps could communicate with it. Another way is that your windows app could save the data in a local file and load them in the UWP app.

Comment: I implemented a tcp server-client communication using SuperSimpleTcp library. It works fine.